# Laravel 5 and remote mysql not working on production

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

In my local environment I have working a secondary remote mysql connection specified in config/database.php without any problems:

```
# Secondary database connection
    'mysql_remote' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', 'cherokee.websitewelcome.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'dbusr'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', 'dbpass'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_2', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

But when I run this on production server with the exact same database file I get the following error, is like the remote host (cherokee.websitewelcome.com) is not used and replace it with local server host (eu01.server.plus)

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbusr'@'eu01.server.plus' (using password: YES) (SQL: select ...)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's used. You are connecting to the Mysql database on `cherokee.websitewelcome.com` with the user `dbusr` which is connecting from `eu01.server.plus`. You need to insure that there is a user `dbusr` on your `mysql` instance with the host of `eu01.server.plus`. `CREATE USER 'dbusr'@'eu01.server.plus' ... `

Comment: I think my server is blocking connections to the remote mysql server, I have tried from the production servers shell connecting to the remote mysql and I get ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbusr'@'eu01.server.plus'

Comment: If you hit up `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` Do you see `winnersm_librous` with a host of `eu01.server.plus` (or `%`) listed? If not you can't connect from that domain with that user. "Access denied" suggests you are hitting the server just fine, you just don't have access with that user/host combination.

Comment: I've got it fixed, was a problem of host permission on remote mysql server, my fault. Thank you @JNevill

Comment: Great! I'm glad you solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding eu01.server.plus to authorized hosts on remote mysql server. Initially I was adding the IP and not hostname.